# Evaluate expression as float in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a function which inputs two variables a, b and which returns a/b as a float irrespective of the types of a and b. Right now I'm doing this as:

```
def f(a, b):
    return float(a)/float(b)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to support the possibility that a and/or b could be strings or just float and/or int?

Comment: @Foon I assume that a, b are always numbers

Comment: You only need one operand to be a float, so `float(a) / b` and `a / float(b)` would both be valid also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python2, put this at the top of the file

```
from __future__ import division
```

now `/` will always give a float. Use `//` for the old behaviour.

If you are using Python3, then this is already the default behaviour of `/`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply force the conversion of one of the operands to the float type, for example:

```
def f(a, b):
    return (a*1.0)/b
```

Comment: `float(a) / b` would do just as well and should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  ;)

The safest way is to do what you have, which will work for every numeric type that can be converted to a `float`.  Some numeric types, such as `Fraction` in Python 3, will still return a `Fraction` even with the new division (which only affects `int`s -- other types define `/` for themselves) but your code will properly turn `Fraction`s into `floats`.